# C++/OpenGL glm Can't plug matrix into uniform in shader

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, glsl, glm-math

I can't use my matrix in my OpenGL shader; this is giving me an error:

```
glUniform4f(matLocation, mat[0], mat[1], mat[2], mat[3]); // glm mat4

no suitable conversion function from "glm::tvec4<float, glm::highp>" to "GLfloat" exists
```

I don't entirely understand *why* it's giving me this error message, and as usual, Googling doesn't give me any good results. Why would it want me to convert matrices to floats?

Comment: A matrix isn't a vec4, you should use glUniformMatrix4fv and glm::value_ptr.

Comment: It's not a vec4, it's a mat4.

Comment: Then why are you using glUniform4f? It sets the four values of a vec4.

Comment: Then what should I be using?

Comment: As I said, glUniformMatrix4fv with the `value` argument being `glm::value_ptr(mat)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glUniform4f` only updates a `vec4` with four float values, so you need `glUniformMatrix4fv` which takes a pointer to an array of 16 float values glm can provide with `glm::value_ptr`.

`mat[n]` only yields the `n`th column, a `vec4`; thus the compilation error.